# Cheap way to measure battery drain in Android

Tags: android

I need to calculate programmitically the battery drain per hour. E.g. 2% per hour average battery drain.

I would ideally need to calculate this value on each screen On, or just before shutdown/reboot on Froyo onwards.

What can be a cheap/battery efficient way to calculate this value?

Answer (score 2):

The Android Developer site has a [page](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) describing how to get information from the battery which includes determining the current battery level.

I suppose you could monitor the small changes and subsequently project what that would mean over a longer period of time. e.g. -0.05% per min = -3% per hour

Comment: some devices are sending me notification when the battery changed -/+10%. It can be better than nothing, but doesn't say how many percent is my app, but the whole app used in phone